# Can you remove a co-op player's character from the party if they stop playing?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

Let's say I decide to start Baldur's Gate 3 with a group of 4 people and one of them decides they don't want to play anymore. What happens to that player's character? Is there a way to remove them from the party?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Patch 2](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/1086940/view/3656414378543586471) added the ability to remove player characters from the party via Withers' Wardrobe. Talk to Withers in camp once you have recruited him:

> Introducing Withers’ Wardrobe of Wayward Friends! With this
> woodworked wonder, you can now dismiss co-op party members and bring
> your companions back into the fold.